# How do I write a unit test for a Spring Cloud Reactive API Gateway's Custom Filter to test if it allows requests to public endpoints to pass?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to write a unit test for a Spring Cloud Reactive API Gateway's authAccountFilter in a microservices architecture. The gateway is using WebFlux and the authAccountFilter is responsible for checking if an endpoint is public or secure. If it is a public endpoint, the request is allowed to pass through. However, if it is a secure endpoint, the authAccountFilter checks for a JWT header before allowing the request to pass.

I have tried multiple approaches and implementations, but I am unable to get my unit test to pass. I suspect that the issue may be with my implementation, but I am not sure.

If anyone could provide some guidance or ideas on how to correctly write this unit test for a Spring Cloud Reactive API Gateway using WebFlux in a microservices architecture, I would greatly appreciate it.

> **GatewayApplication.java :**

```java
package gateway;

import gateway.filters.*; // simplified the import all the filter once (AuthAccountFilter included)
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.EnableHystrix;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableEurekaClient
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableHystrix
public class GatewayApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder rlb, AuthAccountFilter authAccountFilter) {
    return rlb
        .routes()
        .route(p -> p
            .path("/my-service/**")
            .filters(f -> f
                .rewritePath("/my-service/(?<segment>.*)", "/$\\{segment}")
                .filter(authAccountFilter.apply(new AuthAccountFilter.Config())))
            .uri("lb://MY-SERVICE"))
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("... My-Service is UP -- READY TO GO!");
  }
}
```

> **AuthAccountFilter.java :**

```java
package gateway.filters;

import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject;
import com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.json.JSONObject;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class AuthAccountFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthAccountFilter.Config> {

  private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthAccountFilter.class);

  @Autowired
  WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

  @Override
  public Class<Config> getConfigClass() {
    return Config.class;
  }

  public static class Config {
    // empty class as I don't need any particular configuration
  }

  @Override
  public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

    return (exchange, chain) -> {
      String endpoint = exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString();

      LOGGER.trace("Gateway filter for endpoint : " + endpoint);

      LOGGER.info("Checking permission for endpoint : " + endpoint);
      if (exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString().contains("auth") ||
          exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString().contains("otp") ||
          exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString().toLowerCase().contains("reset-password")) {
        LOGGER.info("Public endpoint, aborting filter");
        Mono<Void> filter = chain.filter(exchange);
        System.err.println(filter == null);
        return filter;
      }

    };
  }

}
```

> **AuthAccountFilterTest.java :**

```java
package gateway.filters;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.mock.web.server.MockServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.CoreSubscriber;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class AuthAccountFilterTest {

  private GatewayFilterChain filterChain = mock(GatewayFilterChain.class);

  @Test
  void testPublicEndpoint() {
    String baseUrl = "http://localhost:9090/my-service/";

    // Create a mock request and response
    MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest.get(baseUrl + "auth").build();
    MockServerHttpResponse response = new MockServerHttpResponse();

    // Create an instance of your AuthFilter and any dependencies it has
    AuthAccountFilter filter = new AuthAccountFilter();

    WebFilterChain chain = (exchange, filterChain) -> {
      // Set the Config instance on the Exchange object
      AuthAccountFilter.Config config = new AuthAccountFilter.Config();
      exchange.getAttributes().put("config", config);

      // Call the apply method of the AuthFilter, passing in the Config instance
      return filter.apply(config);
    };
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please create minimal reproducible example and add code to the question instead of posting an external link

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your remark I added code snippet directly into the question

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to test gateway filters is to create integration Spring Boot tests using `WebTestClient`. It will allow to validate end-to-end request handling and make sure that all configurations are defined correctly.

In order to do it you would need to make your routes testable by extracting downstream service URI into configuration properties.

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder rlb, AuthAccountFilter authAccountFilter) {
    return rlb
            .routes()
            .route(p -> p.path("/my-service/*")
                    .filters(f -> f
                            .rewritePath("/my-service/(?<segment>.*)", "/$\\{segment}")
                            .filter(authAccountFilter.apply(new AuthAccountFilter.Config())))
                    .uri(properties.getServiceUri()))
            .build();
}
```

Also, you can use WireMock to mock downstream services and validate that routes are defined correctly.

```
SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0) // random port
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class GatewayConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private GatewayProperties gatewayProperties;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void verifyAuthRequest() {
        // mock downstream service
        stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/auth"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withStatus(200)
                )
        );

        // make request to gateway
        webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/my-service/auth")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();

        verify(1, getRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/auth")));
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestGatewayConfiguration {

        public TestGatewayConfiguration(
                @Value("${wiremock.server.port}") int wireMockPort,
                GatewayProperties properties) {
            properties.setServiceUri("http://localhost:" + wireMockPort);
        }
    }
}
```

This test relies on `AutoConfigureWireMock` and you need to add test dependency to `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock`. As an alternative you can add direct dependency to WireMock and initialize it explicitly.

You can still test your filter using unit tests in isolation using mock request but in your case it provides very little ROI

```
@Test
void filterTest() {
    var filterFactory = new AuthAccountFilter();

    MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest.get("/my-service/auth").build();
    MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.from(request);

    var filter = filterFactory.apply(new AuthAccountFilter.Config());

    GatewayFilterChain filterChain = mock(GatewayFilterChain.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<ServerWebExchange> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ServerWebExchange.class);
    when(filterChain.filter(captor.capture())).thenReturn(Mono.empty());

    StepVerifier.create(filter.filter(exchange, filterChain))
            .verifyComplete();

    var resultExchange = captor.getValue();
    // verify result exchange
}
```

ps

Take a look at Spring Security that would allow you to define the same rules using `SecurityWebFilterChain` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/configuration/webflux.html.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain apiSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/my-service/auth").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/my-service/otp").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/my-service/**/reset-password").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reached this question because I was facing the same challenge when testing WebFilter for a Webflux (SpringBoot) application on Java.

I figured out testing that kind of scenario by using the Spring Cloud Gateway properties:

1. Mock a backend response to mimic the service protected by your filter.

```java
    private static MockWebServer mockExternalBackEnd;
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;
    MyFilter myFilter;

    @Builder
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class StubResponse {
        private String status;
    }

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() throws IOException {
        objectMapper = createObjectMapper();
        mockExternalBackEnd = new MockWebServer();
        mockExternalBackEnd.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() throws IOException {
        mockExternalBackEnd.shutdown();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws JsonProcessingException {
        this.myFilter = new MyFilter();
        // External service to be redirected answers "OK"
        mockExternalBackEnd.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(StubResponse.builder().status(HttpStatus.OK.name()).build()))
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    }
```

2. Configure a route to your protected service (the mocked backend above).

```java
@DynamicPropertySource
    static void updateWebClientConfig(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id", () -> "mock");
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]", () -> "Path=/services/mock/**");
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri",
                () -> String.format("http://localhost:%s", mockExternalBackEnd.getPort()));
    }
```

3. Use WebTestClient to call your protected service, passing through the filter(s).

```java
    @Test
    void testAccessServiceUsingTokenIsOk() {
        webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/services/mock/stub")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isForbidden();
    }
```

For this to work, your SecurityConfiguration should have a pathMatcher that says the "/services/**" path is protected by authentication and your filter is registered:

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

...

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        // Note: Omitted some configurations
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .addFilterAt(new MyFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC)
            .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager())
        .and()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/services/**").authenticated()
        return http.build();
    }

...

}
```

Then you can assert if the service have been contacted and replied with the expected answer:

```java
StubResponse expectedResponse = StubResponse.builder().status(HttpStatus.OK.name()).build();

StubResponse externalServiceResponse = webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/services/mock/stub")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer ...")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(StubResponse.class)
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();
        assertThat(externalServiceResponse).isEqualTo(expectedResponse);
```